# Type {properties .....} is not assignable to type ActionReducer<AdminState,Action> NGRX Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

Using NGRX library for redux, trying to group the state of the application as below

```
export interface ApplicationState {
    adminState: AdminState
}

export interface AdminState {
    adminProductCategory: ProductCategoryState;
    adminProductVendor: VendorState;
    adminProductSubCategory: ProductSubCategoryState;
    products: ProductsState;
    product: ProductState
}
```

For the app module

```
imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25
    })
  ],
```

Index.ts

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState> = {
  adminState: AdminState = {
    adminProductCategory: AdminProductCategoryReducer,
    adminProductVendor: AdminProductVendorReducer,
    adminProductSubCategory: AdminProductSubCategoryReducer,
    products: ProductsReducer,
    product: ProductReducer,
  }
};


export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<ApplicationState>[] = [];
```

Exception

```
Type '{ adminProductCategory: (state: ProductCategoryState, action: Action) => any; adminProductVendor: (state: VendorState, action: Action) => any; adminProductSubCategory: (state: ProductSubCategoryState, action: Action) => any; products: (state: ProductsState, action: Action) => any; product: (state: ProductState, acti...' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<AdminState, Action>'.

'AdminState' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Reducer

```
export function AdminProductCategoryReducer(state: ProductCategoryState | undefined, action: Action): any {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

Comment: I don't think a `AdminProductCategoryReducer` is the same type as `ProductCategoryState`, correct?

Comment: On reducer the state are same, I have updated the question with reducer code.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this message because you're using the `AdminState` as a value `adminState: AdminState` within object brackets `{}`, which is allowed within class/function brackets only.

Try to remove the `AdminState` from this part of the code, and keep it like the following:

```js
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState> = {
  adminState: {
    adminProductCategory: AdminProductCategoryReducer,
    adminProductVendor: AdminProductVendorReducer,
    adminProductSubCategory: AdminProductSubCategoryReducer,
    products: ProductsReducer,
    product: ProductReducer,
  }
};
```

Comment: Still getting an exception  Type '{ adminProductCategory: (state: ProductCategoryState, action: Action) => any; adminProductVendor: (state: VendorState, action: Action) => any; adminProductSubCategory: (state: ProductSubCategoryState, action: Action) => any; products: (state: ProductsState, action: Action) => any; product: (state: ProductState, acti...' provides no match for the signature '(state: AdminState, action: Action): AdminState'.

Comment: Could you please create a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), that simulates what you are trying to do exactly?